# What constitutes shopping questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, closing-questions

I recently stumbled across this question:
[What should I look for in a jump rope?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/10209/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-jump-rope), which was given 2 up-votes and reasonable answers.

Should this be closed as a shopping question?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 5):

> Should this be closed as a shopping question?

Looks like there are no close votes on it, so no.

This is not a purchase recommendation question; it asks what qualities one should look for in a piece of equipment.

FrederickD's answer (the best one so far) doesn't even mention a particular product in the answer.

> What constitutes shopping questions?

Here are some examples.

- [My current office chair makes back ache](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/my-current-office-chair-makes-back-ache): "can you recommend any brand or even a specific chair?"
- [Ginseng supplement recommendation](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7215/ginseng-supplement-recommendation): "Could you recommend some ginseng supplement [...]"
- https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6986/usn-100-whey-protein: "Just wondering if anyone has tried or know about USN's 100% whey protein?"
- https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/does-a-rowing-machine-exist-that-is-both-compact-and-reliable: "Does anyone know of a rower that is small but can be used every day providing good resistance? I would be willing to pay for this!"

Comment: Then what's wrong with this question? http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6615/tips-on-choosing-a-stopwatch-for-interval-training

Comment: Moderation on this site sucks. I'm outtie, peace.

Comment: @masonk well, NOW its okay, but only AFTER Informaficker edited it. All that would be needed now is a reopening vote. But since "youre outie", i guess im wasting myt breath/keyboard

Comment: @K.L. It's true that I don't visit this site anymore, but your comment popped up in my stack exchange header bar. The question was closed after the edit to its current form. And I really don't care enough to do something like that.